# how do i set cookies in php for twitter?

Tags: php, cookies, twitter

i have this varibale that i got from the database, that i want to store in a cookie to post to twitter,

i.e

```
$_COOKIE['oauth_token']=$row['oauth_token'];
```

but how i set the cookie!!! thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use [`setcookie('oauth_token',...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). But I don't think that does what you want it to do. You cannot set cookies for foreign domains.

Comment: no its for my domain, im using the twitter api, but i need set the cookie, thanks mario!!! :))

Answer (score 1):

you can store a cookie locally using `setcookie()` but that cannot be used for 'posting to twitter', unless its just a temporary location to store the data, and you're posting the data via another means.

its worth looking at http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/ if you're wanting to authenticate with external systems over OAuth.